# How to insert to the mysql array object

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs, rest

I'm new to Rest api,I'm developing a student management system using rest api and angular js.When I registering students from student registration form there is a ng-grid to select courses of students going attend in the institute,
I loaded selected courses in an angular object like this.

```
var Course = {
        "std_id": "1",
        "course_id": $scope.studentCourse,
        "started_date": $scope.startedDate
};
```

in this courses object courses are selected values from ng-grid plus student and registrations date.My problem is I have loaded objects to an object and Im stuck with process this obejects in side my restfull api.

my json object pass like this

```
[{  
"std_id":"1",
"courses":
[{"course_id":"2"},
    {"course_id":"4"},
    {"course_id":"8"}],
"started_date":"2015-9-18"
}]
```

Here my php rest call

```
    private function InsertStudentCourse() {
        if ($this->get_request_method() != "POST") {
        $this->response('', 406);
        }
        $course= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        $column_names = array ('std_id','course_id','started_date');
        $columns = '';
        $values = '';
        $keys = array_keys($course);

        //$this->response($this->json($deviceTypeId), 200);
        foreach ($column_names as $desired_key) { // Check the Department received. If blank insert blank into the array.
            if (!in_array($desired_key, $keys)) {
                $$desired_key = '';
            } else {
                    $$desired_key = $course[$desired_key];
            }
            $columns = $columns . $desired_key . ',';
            $values = $values . "'" . $$desired_key . "',";
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO student_course (" . trim($columns, ',') . ") VALUES(" . trim($values, ',') . ")";

    //$query = "INSERT INTO student_course ('course_id') VALUES ($c)";

    if (!empty($course)) {
        $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error . __LINE__);
        $success = array('status' => "Success", "msg" => "student Course Type Created Successfully.", "data" => $course);
        $this->response($this->json($success), 200);
    } else {
        $this->response('', 204);
    } //"No Content" status
}
```

I want to insert this object array like this

```
    
    
    std_id  course_id    started_date
    - 1 ,       2,         2015-9-18
    - 1 ,       4,         2015-9-18
    - 1 ,       8,         2015-9-18
```

how can I get this done

Comment: I would strongly suggest you only send one course at a time.... and send it at the time it is created or edited. It appears you are over complicating it by sending groups in a structure that doesn't really make sense. How did the data that is sent get it's structure changed from the way that `Course` is structured?

Comment: it almost pass with student basic details as an json object it working perfect,I use the response to get std_id to the next to proceed as course registrations [link] (http://www.izarsolution.esy.es/#/studentManagement/newStudent)